# How to close the dynamically added pop-up when user clicks anywhere on the page outside of that pop-up's surface?

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, jquery-ui-dialog, thickbox

I'm using one jQuery pop-up library called **thickbox.js**.

There is one small image present on my page. When user clicks on this image a call to some function is given, the thickbox.js library creates the HTML/CSS for pop-up on the fly and shows up the pop-up.

The most important thing to note here is if the HTML source of page is viewed when the pop-up is shown I'm not able to see the HTML code of pop-up. I tried to view the HTML source of pop-up through Firebug console by inspecting the element then I could see the HTML source of pop-up. This indicates that the DOM doesn't contain the HTML code of pop-up box.

Now my issue is I want to close this opened pop-up if user clicks anywhere on the page other than the pop-up area. I tried few codes but unfortunately they are not able to do the thing I want to do. Now I'm just clueless for this issue. Following is the code for your reference:

```
<a href="#" onclick="return $Core.box('prj_name.contactform', 400);"> 
<!-- This is the function call which generates the pop-up HTML on the fly -->
  <img width="33" height="89" align="middle" border="0" pagespeed_url_hash="3893298907" alt="" src="http://58.189.67.789/theme/frontend/foxplus/style/default/image/layout/contact.jpeg">
</a>
```

Following is the pop-up HTML generated dynamically. I've taken from Firebug console:

```
<div class="js_box_image_holder_full ">
  <div id="js_box_id_3" class="js_box " style="width: 400px; top: 15%; left: 69%; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 278px; z-index: 5003; display: block;">
    <div class="js_box_title">Contact</div>
    <div class="js_box_content">
      <style type="text/css">#js-contact-message:after{content:'\1f603'}</style>
      <div id="js_contact_message">Your details submit succesfully</div>
      <div id="js_contact_error_message"></div>
      <iframe style="display:none" name="js_contact_frame" id="js_contact_frame" frameborder="1" width="100%"> </iframe>
      <div class="main_break">
        <form method="post" action="http://58.189.67.789/prj_name/contact/" id="js_contact_form" target="js_contact_frame">     
          <div class="table">
            <div class="p_left">
              <label for="email">Full Name</label>
            </div>
            <div class="p_right">
              <input name="val[full_name]" id="full_name" value="" size="60" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="table">
            <div class="p_left">
              <label for="email">Email</label>
            </div>
            <div class="p_right">
              <input name="val[email]" id="email" value="" size="30" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="table">
            <div class="p_left">
              <label for="text">Message</label>
            </div>
            <div class="p_right">
              <textarea name="val[text]" id="text"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="table" style="display:none;">
            <div class="p_left">Send Yourself a Copy</div>
          <div class="p_right">
            <input name="val[copy]" value="1" type="checkbox">
          </div>
          <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="table_clear">
          <input value="Submit" class="button" type="submit">
          <div class="t_right"><span id="js_comment_process"></span></div>
        </div>  
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="js_box_title_store">Contact</div>
  </div>
  <div style="display: block;" class="js_box_close">
    <a href="#" onclick="return js_box_remove(this);">x</a>
    <span class="js_box_history">prj_name.contactform</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

The jQuery codes I tried are as follows:

```
$('body').click(function(e) {
  if( $('.js_box_image_holder_full').length ) {
    if (!$(e.target).closest('.js_box_image_holder_full').length) {
      $('.js_box_image_holder_full').hide();
    }
  }
});
```

The second code I tried is as follows:

```
$(document).click(function(event) { 
  if(!$(event.target).closest('.js_box_image_holder_full').length) {
    if($('.js_box_image_holder_full').is(":visible")) {
      $('.js_box_image_holder_full').hide()
    }
  }        
})
```

The issue with both of the above code snippets is the pop-up doesn't open up when user clicks on image. Also I didn't get any error or warning in a Firebug console.

The third code snippet I tried:

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
  var container = $(".js_box");

  if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {

    $(".js_box_image_holder_full").remove();
  }
});
```

The issue I get with above code is the opened pop-up gets closed if user clicks anywhere on page other than the surface of pop-up but when user again clicks on the image to show the pop-up it doesn't come again. This time also I didn't get any error or warning in Firebug console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not use any sort of plugin for popup, but I have simple solution for you. On trigger, fade in an empty mask beside popup and make the mask an agent for fade out. Shown below.

```js
$(function(){
    $('.clickme').click(function(){
        $('.popup,.mask').fadeIn();
    });
    $('.mask').click(function(){
        $('.popup,.mask').fadeOut();
    });
});
```

```css
.clickme{
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    padding:10px;
    background:#00cfff;
    color:#fff;
}
.mask{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    z-index:2;
    display:none;
}
.popup{
    display:none;
    position:fixed;
    top:20px;
    left:20px;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:#d30043;
    z-index:3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='outer'>
    <span class='clickme'>Click Me</span>
    <div class='mask'></div>
    <div class='popup'>I am a Popup</div>
</div>
```